# How to run case counts by group?

Tags: sql, count, sum, case

I am just beginning to teach myself SQL (I've been going at it for a week now and feel I have been doing pretty well to this point).

I have a practice database that I'm just messing around with -- there are two tables (one titled "progress" and one titled "users").

Progress
This table includes a foreign key from "users" identifying students enrolled in 5 different coding courses (CPP, SQL, HTML, Javascript, and Java) and indicates whether a student is enrolled, has started a course, or has completed a course.

Users
This table includes the primary key for identifying students as well as their demographic information (addresses, email domain for university, etc...).

I want to be able to count the number of students enrolled in the 5 courses for each university. I have been able to do this for one university at a time but I want something that will do that for all 617 different universities at once.

```
WITH placeholder AS (
    SELECT *
        FROM users
            JOIN progress
                ON users.user_id = progress.user_id
        GROUP BY email_domain
        ORDER BY email_domain
)
select email_domain,
       Sum(CASE WHEN learn_cpp = "completed" OR learn_cpp = "started" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CPP Enrollment',
       Sum(CASE WHEN learn_sql = "completed" OR learn_SQL = "started" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'SQL Enrollment',
       Sum(CASE WHEN learn_html = "completed" OR learn_html = "started" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'HTML Enrollment',
       Sum(CASE WHEN learn_javascript = "completed" OR learn_javascript = "started" THEN 1 Else 0 END) AS 'Javascript Enrollment',
       Sum(CASE WHEN learn_java = "completed" OR learn_java = "started" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Java Enrollment'
    FROM placeholder;
```

This returns the correct enrollment count across all universities but only has the first university email domain (shown below).

aa.edu  238 317 183 306 119

I want the enrollment counts for each course by university (there should be 167 rows with enrollment counts for each course in the columns).

Comment: Have you tried adding to GROUP BY the University and the Course?  (and Order By) And moving those after "from Placeholder"

Comment: donPablo is a genius

Answer (score 0):

donPablo caught this quickly in the comments.

I moved my GROUP BY and ORDER BY commands out of the join table command and to the end of my code so that it would be run after enrollment counts have been calculated.

This produced the result I was looking for.

Thank you for your quick response!